Blank screen on SilverStripe 3.7.2 after leaving session opened for several hours in multiple tabs and saving changes, changes lost
I would appreciate if anyone could shred some light into this problem and if possible, solve it.
A client of mine is experiencing an issue which relates to editing several products on his SilverStripe 3.7.2 site (updates info on the products listed, adds new products, etc) when leaving the session open for several hours and multiple tabs opened at the same time. When coming back to edit further and Save, he gets a blank screen and all changes lost. He has to start all over again.
After several testing - need to point out that the cookie session expires in 3 months, so I guess is not a time out thing - we concluded that the problem only presents itself when having multiple Products opened at the same time after a big amount of time. The problem doesn't present itself if having only one tab opened.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue? Does anyone know why it happens? And most important, does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!
Cookie life is 90 days. But it seems it is not related to the session life but having multiple products opened after several hours. We extended the time for this, having a clean browser and forcing this by checking the 'Remember me' check box when logging in. This didn't solve the problem.
